# The meaning of "multiparadigm design pattern(s)"

Tags: design-patterns, terminology

Can anyone please explain to me what "Multiparadigm design pattern(s)" term means?
I'm OK with "design patterns" but the word "multiparadigm" confuses me.

Comment: Never heard of it, but then I'm not a DP guru. Where did you encounter this?

Comment: It was a required skill in one vacancy.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of programming, "paradigm" often refers to object-oriented, procedural, functional, logical, etc. So "multiparadigm" would be referring to something as relating to features of several paradigms. E.g. Scala is a multiparadigm language supporting both object-oriented and functional programming.

The phrase "multiparadigm design pattern" probably doesn't have a specific technical meaning; it's just someone talking about design patterns that they wish to describe as multiparadigm. Maybe a design pattern that uses techniques from more than one paradigm? To say more about what exactly they mean by that description I'd need to see more context than just those three words.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I saw it as one of the compulsory skills in one vacancy for java developer.

Answer (score 0):

For another take on this, I refer you to James Coplien in his work on Multiparadigm Design for C++: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Multiparadigm-Design-James-O-Coplien/dp/0201824671

In it he discusses a wide variety of abstraction methods including templates (analogous to generics in Java/c#), generic functions, procedural, object and functional paradigms. The focus of the work is on analysing domains to discover what paradigm(s) best fit - where one hasn't already been established.

A programmer who has a solid grasp of several paradigms will have more options when it comes to conceiving solutions. Some problems are a good fit for polymorphism, inheritance etc others are more elegantly built with functional concepts or generic programming. A larger system is likely to benefit from modules that may well mix these. Anything mathematically intense that needs to be accurate, I'm likely to consider functional first but UI on top? OOP most likely.

Many languages are now multiparadigm: Java primarily OOP, yet now has generics and version 8 has lambdas -  functional construct. C#/Vb had these for quite a long time now and F# turns this around to be functional first.